# Animate slide from left in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/3421/). Why am I not able to animate the `toc`div?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="wrapper">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="toc">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="pull-right"><a href="#" id="slidetoLeft"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> </a> 
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery is:

```
$("#slidetoLeft").on("click", function () {
    $("#toc").animate({
        "left": "0px",
        "slow");
 });
```

Comment: Check the console.. there were syntax errors.. http://jsfiddle.net/32p36/

Comment: Thanks JoshC , but how can I add some more properties like easing or speed units(like Slow or 4000) to the function then?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/36nTx/

Comment: Yeah exactly, thanks. I just need to add toggle mode to the function to be able to pull back the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle. Changed the code like

```
 $(".glyphicon").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    $("#toc").animate({ "left": "0px" }, "slow");
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3423/)

Comment: Thanks Anoop, but can you please also let me know how I can add toggle  to the function as well? I mean been able to pull back the div to original position?

Comment: @user1760110 have u checked this?